# Keeping A Video Centered, allowing left overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, center

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I am wondering how to get a hero background video to stay centered in the page no matter what, such as this http://thisisdk.com/

Purely through css, or through very minimal js.

The problem I have had is that I cannot keep the video in the center while resizing the window. I am okay with cropping! I just want it in the center without resizing.

This is my current test page, https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96682768/VidTest.html

```
#intVid {
position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
width: auto; height: 100%; z-index: -100;
background-size: cover;}

<video id="intVid" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" ><source src="showtest.mp4"     type="video/mp4">bgvideo</video>
```

I have searched the web for a few hours and found no solution... not sure if this is over my head.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you tried background-position: center; ?

Comment: Stumbled over the same here, any updates?